# What does it mean geometrically that $H^*(B\mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}[a]$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I found cited in a physics paper that $H^*(B\mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}_2[a]$ and I wanted to know what geometric shapes this corresponded to.  Notice the answer is a polynomial ring.  Here $\mathbb{Z}2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Wikipedia's article on [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) refers to homotopy theory and gives the example that the circle $S^1$ is the classifying space for the infinite cycle group $\mathbb{Z}$.  This is written as $E\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R}$ and they are discussing the "universal bundle".

I'd like a more down-to-earth explication.  What kind of objects are being represented by the classifying space of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and what do the equivalences classes in the cohomology ring look like?

What could mod-2 cohomology be measuring about the shape of the space?  Here it says $M_3$ could we could have $M = S^3 / i(S^1)$ with some reasonable map $i : S^1 \to S^3 = \mathbb{R}^3 \cup \{ pt\}$  (a "knot").  This is taken from a Physics paper from arXiv which I am still looking at [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.11959)].

---

Just to collect from the comments:

- $B\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the classifying space of principal $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundles over paracompact spaces.  What I am seeing is an perfectly good abstract definition:

> For a discrete group $G = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is ... a path-connected topological space $X$ such that the fundamental group of $X$ is isomorphic to $G$ and the higher homotopy groups are trivial.

Since I have only read through Munkres and Hatcher the last parts of that sentence are challenging. 
It sounds like we could just say "two-sheet [cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space)".

- The cohomology ring of [real projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space#Homology) $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty, \mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}_2[a]$ which is thes same as the ring in question. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64675/cohomology-ring-structure-of-conf-mathbbrm-3?rq=1) they do mention that for the configuration space of three points on a sphere $H^*(S^{m-1}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}[a]/(a^2) $ so this is already a much smaller ring than the answer that we have.
- Reading through the definition of [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space#Paracompact_Hausdorff_spaces) space we have, at least that metric spaces are paracompact and [CW complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) are paracompact.

Here "geometric" just means "shape".  Here's another possible question... why are 2-sheeted covers of CW complexes classified by a polynoial ring?

Comment: $B\Bbb{Z}_2$ is the classifying space for principal $\Bbb{Z}_2$-bundles over paracompact spaces. You can identify principal $\Bbb{Z}_2$-bundles with two-sheeted covers, so $[X,B\Bbb{Z}_2]$ is in one-to-one correspondence with two-sheeted covers over a paracompact space $X$. $B\Bbb{Z}_2$ is a $K(\Bbb{Z}_2,1)$, so this space is (up to homotopy) $\Bbb{R}P^\infty$, whose cohomology ring (with $\Bbb{Z}_2$ coefficients) is the one in your first sentence.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your last sentence about $M_3$ and such is referring to; it's not set up earlier in your question and seems unrelated to your first few paragraphs, unless you are simply asking what singular cohomology measures about the topology you have; this probably has a good answer somewhere on MSE.

Comment: @kamills what do you mean [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space)? Let's say $M = S^3$ or a knot complement.  We are looking at open covers of $S^3$ or various distance metrics on $S^3$ ?

Comment: A more geometric interpretation of $B\mathbb{Z}/2$ is that it classifies rank 1 vector bundles. This is because $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is equivalent to $O(1)=\mathbb{R}^\times$.

Comment: @cactus314: Lots of spaces are paracompact (e.g., smooth manifolds, CW complexes). When I said "cover" in my comment above, I meant covering space. But I think Connor's comment is more geometric and closer to what you might want: the classifying space for real line bundles is $BO(1)$, which as mentioned is the same as $B\Bbb{Z}_2$. So isomorphism classes of real line bundles are in one-to-one correspondence with $[X,BO(1)] = [X, B\Bbb{Z}_2]$.

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear how to respond to your question without knowing more about your background in topology. In any case, this answer will mostly repeat things that have already been said in the comments.

$B \mathbb{Z}_2$ can be thought of as either the classifying space of principal $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundles (which correspond to double covers) or as the classifying space $BO(1)$ of [real line bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_bundle). Maybe the most "geometric" description of it is that it is an infinite [real projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space) $\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$, so you can get some intuition for it by studying the finite real projective spaces.

If $M$ is path-connected and maybe satisfies some other mild hypotheses then homotopy classes of maps $M \to B \mathbb{Z}_2$ are computed by

$$H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \text{Hom}(H_1(M), \mathbb{Z}_2).$$

As far as the cohomology calculation goes, the generating class $a$ corresponds to the [first Stiefel-Whitney class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class) $w_1 \in H^1(-, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ of a real line bundle. Loosely speaking it measures how the line bundle "twists" (more formally, it is measuring [monodromy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy), which the identification with $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), \mathbb{Z}_2)$ also suggests), and is zero iff the line bundle is trivial(izable). The fact that the cohomology (over $\mathbb{Z}_2$) is the polynomial algebra on $w_1$ says that every [characteristic class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class) of real line bundles is a polynomial in $w_1$ and that $w_1$ is free in the sense that it satisfies no polynomial relations. This reflects the fact that, by the computation above, it can take on any value in $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ for any $M$.

The fact that $BO(2) \cong B \mathbb{Z}_2$ says that $w_1$ is a complete invariant of real line bundles: two real line bundles $L, L'$ are isomorphic iff $w_1(L) = w_1(L')$.

It's unclear whether any of this constitutes an answer to your question; it would help if you were more specific about which of this most sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: it's physics paper it just says "$B\mathbb{Z}_2$"